How verifier will get secret key to verify JWT token in symmetric cryptography?
Symmetric Cryptography:
A single secret key is used for both creating and validating the token. Both the issuer and the verifier need to have access to this key.
But how   verifier will get this secret key?
like i will send him personally or it will store in cloud/DB .so he/she can access it , or i will send in mail,teams....

Looking ar RFC 7516, if the token is encrypted, the symmetric key (and IV) is a part of the token. Nothing to do with validation though - the token signature is not generated with the symmetric algorithm, they conceptually don't support signatures. For the signature, usually SHAx-HMAC, RSA, or [EC-]DSA is used, and that's what you use for validation.
